# How can we find out if an android app is crashed using adb shell command

Tags: android, robotframework

I am automating some android application say for example phone application using robot framework, so I have set of test cases, Now I want to know whether the phone application is running or crashed during the entire test case execution, if an application is crashed, i would send some message saying application is crashed

Comment: Did you look at how CTS runs it's set of JUnit tests? Perhaps it leads you an idea ;)

But adb won't be of much help there; at best you can do via adb is to attach GDB to the process just before it dies to have a good look at values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I dont have any idea about CTS, anyways i will check about it.

Comment: CTS is the Android Compatibility Test Suite, a bunch of JUnit tests supposed to be ran on the board to confirm that your hardware conforms to Android expectations so it can wear the "Android device" label.